# Django ModelChoiceField initial value not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've got the following form:

```
class AddGameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    shelf = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Shelf.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(AddGameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shelf'].queryset = Shelf.objects.filter(owner=self.user)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['name', 'status', 'hours', 'minutes', 'platform', 'notes', 'shelf']
```

and I want to set the initial value of `shelf`. I've tried this, but it doesn't work, at all.

```
shelf = GameShelfJunction.objects.filter(game_id=game).first()
form = AddGameForm(instance=game, initial={'shelf': shelf.pk}, user=request.user)
```

I can't find anything online with a solution other than using the `initial` kwarg, so I'm kind of lost. Does this have to do with me using the `__init__` function to filter the queryset?

Comment: Since you pass an instance, the initial value will always come from that instance; the `initial` kwarg will be ignored in this case.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there a way to set the initial shelf value while passing an instance? the `shelf` field isn't related to the `game` instance at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add this inside **init** function:

```
self.initial['shelf'] = YOUR_INITIAL_VALUE
```

where YOUR_INITIAL_VALUE is the value you want shelf is initialized with.

Comment: Huh. Apparently it did, but firefox cached the previous requests.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was putting a default-argument in models.py

```
# models.py
shelf =  models.ForeignKey(Shelf.objects.all(), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default='pk_you_want_as_initial')
```